# Using EasyCostumLabeling tool with expression based label?

Tags: qgis, labeling

[image]I'm using an expression based label (my label display 3 fields from my table on aqueduct line) but the resulting label create overlay. Is there a way to prohibition overlapping label from the same layer, but show ALL label? 
Or is there a way to use EasyCustomLabeling tool with expression based label ?

My code look like :

```
"EG_DIAM_SECTION_TBD_SHORT_VALUE"  || 'ø - E.P.  '  ||    "EG_MATERIEL_SECTION_TBD_SHORT_VALUE"  || '\n' ||  "EG_SECTION_LONGUEUR"  ||  'm. @ '||  "EG_SECTION_POURCENTAGE_PENTE"  || '% - ' ||  "EG_SECTION_ANNEE_INSTALLATION"
```

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of how your labels are overlapping? I think with several options I may be able to answer your question. Also, provide the expression you used with your label.

Comment: I found it! I created a concatenated fields in my table and then I used this new field with easycustumlabeling tool! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found it! I created a concatenated fields in my table and then I used this new field with easycustumlabeling tool